# Derivatives of functions with arbitrary number of variables?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, expression-manipulation

I am trying to define a function `f[x1,x2,...,xn]` with `n` integer but not specified. And then I would like this funktion to behave properly under the derivative operation, so that `D[f[x1,x2,...,xn],xi]` actually results in an expression which unambiguously displays that it is the first derivative in respect to the `i`-th variable. Up until now I had little success in employing the Mathematica function `D[x_,y_]` and have been simply substituting it for a place holder `d[x_,y_]`. However, this is not very convenient, since those placeholders do not respect commutativity. Maybe there is such functionality already, which I do not know of? Or maybe one can implement it? Thank you for any suggestion!

**EDIT:**

Please note, I am not looking to define custom functions of a finite number of variables tied to the derivative operation. What I am actually interested in, is defining a function which is dependent on an *unspecified* number of variables `n`. And introducing a formalism such that taking derivatives in respect to one of these variables of an unspecified index `i` still works consistently.

**EDIT2:**

To explain what I mean in more detail, I would like to be able to define a function `f[v]` in which I would like to treat `v` as a 1-dimensional list `v={v1,v2,v3,...,vn}`. However, I would like to keep the amount of elements in `v` arbitrary (without specifying to a certain length). And then I would like to define a derivative operation, which would allow expressions like `D[f[v],v1]` or `D[f[v],v2]` and even `D[f[v],vi]` which should not evaluate to zero, but to some meaningful expression, from which I still could extract the information which derivative it is, and with respect to which of the `n` variables.

Comment: Remember that you can use `Derivative[n][f]`

Comment: When you try `D[f[x1, x2, xn], x2]` you do get an unambiguous result, right? So I think you have to state the problem more clearly with an example.

Comment: The answer in the tagged question above does not answer my actual question. I will edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: This may be related to or perhaps is a duplicate of [symbolic-derivative-of-n-term-product](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19460/symbolic-derivative-of-n-term-product).

Comment: It seems to me that this is not a duplicate, but I'm not sure what the OP ask can be done at all. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @rhermans I'm not sure. The OP hasn't answered why the default `Derivative[n][f]` isn't a convenient notation.

Comment: `Derivative[n][f]` denotes an unspecified number of derivatives with respect to a single variable. What I need is a notation that denotes an unspecified number of derivatives with respect to an unspecified number of variables unambiguously, which clearly cannot be captured by merely `Derivative[n][f]`.

Comment: Ok. voting to reopen

Comment: @rhermans Can you explain what you think the OP means? I do not understand it. This may be because the question is too broad and "formalism" is not defined.

Comment: I have got the same problem. Have you already solve it? Could you please tell me the method? Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

I hope this toy example helps.

First I define some function of an arbitrary number of arguments, such that

```
f[v1, v2, v3,...] == v1 + 2 v2 + 3 v3 + ...
```

I do this with

```
f[v__] := Plus @@ MapIndexed[#1 First@#2 &, {v}, {1}]
```

I can then, without knowing the exact number of arguments, take a derivative with respect to a given argument by

```
i = 3
Derivative[Sequence@@(ConstantArray[0,i-1]~Join~{1})][f]
(* 3 & *)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't allow a purely symbolic approach. I can't clear the `i` and do this:

```
Clear[i]
Derivative[Sequence@@(ConstantArray[0,i-1]~Join~{1})][f]
(* i & <--- ain't happening *)
```

Also problems arise if the derivative is dependent on the number of arguments. e.g.

```
f[v__] := Times @@ MapIndexed[Exp[#1] First@#2 &, {v}, {1}]
Derivative[0, 1][f]
(* 2 E^(#1 + #2) & *)
Derivative[0, 1, 0][f]
(* 6 E^(#1 + #2 + #3) & *)
```

Comment: And now I realize, I'm necroposting. Hopefully my activity will attract someone with a better solution.

Comment: Necroposting is certainly not frowned upon here, long as you make a meaningful contribution.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I think you expressed very clearly what I think the OP is asking for when you say you "can't clear the **i**"? If we could clear the **i** that would be the solution I think. Maybe it would be worth adding that into the question? Just trying to get some attention to this as I would love to have a solution.