# Wrong derivative for a function that I try to define without explicitly giving number of variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, expression-manipulation

What I actually want is to define functions depending on the number of variables which will be specified during some computation. My (probably wrong) attempt is

```
f[x, y, z] /. {f -> (With[{s = {##}}, Product[g[i][s[[i]]], {i, Length[s]}]] &)}
```

The output is correct,

```
g[1][x] g[2][y] g[3][z]
```

but when I try instead

```
Derivative[1,0,0][f][x,y,z]/.{f->(With[{s={##}},Product[g[i][s[[i]]],{i,Length[s]}]]&)}
```

I get zero.

Of course

```
Derivative[1,0,0][f][x,y,z]/.{f->(g[1][#1]g[2][#2]g[3][#3]&)}
```

correctly gives

```
g[2][y] g[3][z] Derivative[1][g[1]][x]
```

but this version does not suit me as I don't know beforehand how many variables will my `f` have.

I found seemingly what I need - an answer to [Derivatives of functions with arbitrary number of variables?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64103/35000), but cannot figure out how to use it here.

Comment: Try to define `f` as a function `f[s__] := Product[g[i][{s}[[i]]], {i, Length[{s}]}]`. This way `Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x, y, z]` returns the correct result.

Comment: for fun, a shorter version of your code: `f[x, y, z] /. {f -> (Times @@ MapIndexed[(g @@ #2)@#1 &, {##}] &)}`.

Comment: @roman465 Could you make this into an answer? It works fine indeed.