# Gradient of function with arbitrary number of variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, expression-manipulation

This [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64103/derivatives-of-functions-with-arbitrary-number-of-variables) answers the question on how to express the derivative of a function with an arbitrary number of variables. However, what if I wanted the gradient? More specifically, if `f[x1,...,xn]` is a given function where `n` may vary, then how would I express its gradient? I could alway do a `Do` loop, but is there an easier way?

EDIT:
More specifically, I would like a function `F[f_,n_]` that has `f` and the number of arguments `n` of function `f` as inputs. `F[f_,n_]` should output the gradient of `f`.

Comment: What about the function `Grad[]`? This seems to what you are looking for at first glance

Comment: @Dunlop That requires inputting the arguments, i.e., `Grad[f[x1,...,xn],{x1,...,xn}]`, which isn't ideal in writing a function that takes in only a function `f` and the number of argument `n`.

Comment: @Andrew Yuan Why do not you make a custom gradient, as for example, `myGrad[expr_]:=Grad[expr,{x1,x2,...xn}]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f, F, n]
F[f_, n_] := Grad[f @ ##, {##}] & @@ Array[\[FormalX], n]
```

***Examples:***

```
F[Times, 3]
```

> {[FormalX][2] [FormalX][3], [FormalX][1] [FormalX][3], [FormalX][
>          1] [FormalX][2]}

```
F[Sin[Total[{##}^2]] &, 2]
```

> {2 [FormalX][1] Cos[[FormalX][1]^2 + [FormalX][2]^2], 
>        2 [FormalX][2] Cos[[FormalX][1]^2 + [FormalX][2]^2]}

Alternatively, use the variable as an additional argument (instead of using `\[FormalX]`:

```
ClearAll[f, F2, n]
F2[f_, n_, var_: x] := Grad[f@##, {##}] & @@ Array[var, n]
```

***Examples:***

```
F2[Times, 3]
```

> {x[2] x[3], x[1] x[3], x[1] x[2]}

```
F2[Sin[Total[{##}^2]] &, 2, z]
```

> {2 Cos[z[1]^2 + z[2]^2] z[1], 2 Cos[z[1]^2 + z[2]^2] z[2]}